# Can I split email hosting between two providers?

Tags: email, google-apps, shared-hosting

If I have 1 user on my domain using google apps to host email. Is it possible to have a 2nd user using a different host?

e.g

- user1@example.com - google apps
- user2@example.com - godaddy

Thanks!

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://superuser.com ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**No**, you can't do this with a single domain. That's because configuring Google Apps requires setting up your DNS in such a way that your hosting provider is out of the email loop entirely.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you actually *can* do this with a single domain. You accomplish this with Google App's [Gmail App Routing Settings](https://support.google.com/a/topic/2921034?hl=en&ref_topic=14867) from the Google Apps Admin Console.

What you would do, is you would set Google Apps as your primary MX provider for your primary domain (MX Records for yourdomain.com would point to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM, et cetera) which would make Google Apps your domain's mail provider. You would then [add your GoDaddy email servers as Hosts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2614757?hl=en) in the settings for the Gmail app in the Console. Then the next step is to [setup your Routes](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2368153?hl=en) so that when Google Apps receives an email meant for someone left on GoDaddy, Google Apps itself will re-route that email to your email servers on GoDaddy, and to the intended recipient. Finally, you'll want to set up on GoDaddy an Outbound Relay, so your outbound mail from GoDaddy goes through your Google Apps servers. Don't forget to set up SPF and DKIM email authentication.

For all your Routing needs, a good place to start would be the Google Apps Help page for Routing: https://support.google.com/a/topic/2921034?hl=en&ref_topic=14867

---

Your Mail Flow: (source: [After your transition: Google Apps mail flow diagrams](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3155880?hl=en))
[image: Your Mail Flow for Receiving Emails, and Where They Would Route to GoDaddy vs a Gmail Inbox]

Comment: It would not be necessary to have a user license for every user who would have their email address on GoDaddy. You would set up a route to redirect emails to specific non-Apps addresses or all addresses that don't have an Apps inbox to GoDaddy.